# Okteto CLI: Trust a custom CA certificate

Tags: go, ssl, ssl-certificate, okteto

While going over [Getting Started on Okteto Cloud with PHP](https://www.okteto.com/docs/samples/php/) tutorial and getting the “certificate signed by unknown authority” error when running `okteto init`. I believe it’s related to the custom zscaler CA that our company defines.

How can I have okteto cli to trust custom CA? As far as I understand it's developed in golang, but setting SSL_CERT_FILE and SSL_CERT_DIR with the location of the certificates didn't help.

```
➜ php-getting-started git:(main) okteto init
i Using … @ cloud.okteto.com as context
✓ Okteto manifest (okteto.yml) deploy and build configured successfully
? Do you want to launch your development environment? [Y/n]: y
i Building ‘Dockerfile’ in tcp://buildkit.cloud.okteto.net:443…
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
x Error building service ‘hello-world’: error building image ‘registry.cloud.okteto.net/.../php-hello-world:1.0.0’: build failed: failed to dial gRPC: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = “transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported on the latest build (2.15.3), but is scheduled to be released on the next.

The fix is already merged, and available on the dev channel:

```
export OKTETO_CHANNEL=dev
curl https://get.okteto.com -sSfL | sh
```

https://community.okteto.com/t/allowing-custom-certificates-in-okteto-cli/828 has more information on this.